# Show that the solution of an autonomous SDE is a time-homogeneous Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a complete probability space and $$\mathcal N:=\left\{N\in\mathcal A:\operatorname P[N]=0\right\}$$
- $(W_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$W^{(s)}_t:=W_{s+t}-W_s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for $s\ge0$
- $b,\sigma:[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be Borel measurable with $$|b(t,x)|^2+|\sigma(t,x)|^2\le K(1+|x|^2)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb R\tag1$$ and $$|b(x)-b(y)|^2+|\sigma(x)-\sigma(y)|^2\le K|x-y|^2\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in\mathbb R\tag2$$ for some $K\ge0$

We know that for all $s\ge0$ there is a real-valued continuous process $\left(X^{(s,\:x)}_t\right)_{(t,\:x)\in[s,\:\infty)\times\mathbb R}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$X^{(s,\:x)}_t=x+\int_s^tb\left(X^{(s,\:x)}_r\right)\:{\rm d}r+\int_s^t\sigma\left(X^{(s,\:x)}_r\right)\:{\rm d}W_r\tag3$$ for all $t\ge s$ almost surely for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Now, let $\xi$ be a real-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ independent of $W$ and $$\mathcal F_t:=\sigma(\xi)\vee\sigma(W_s:s\in[0,t])\vee\mathcal N\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$ Now, there is a real-valued $\mathcal F$-adapted continuous process $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ with $$X_t=\xi+\int_0^tb(X_s)\:{\rm d}s+\int_0^t\sigma(X_s)\:{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$ $X$ is a $\mathcal F$-Markov process with $$\operatorname P\left[X_t\in B\mid\mathcal F_s\right]=\kappa_{s,\:t}(X_s,B)\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }t\ge0\text{ and }B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R),\tag4$$ where $$\kappa_{s,\:t}(x,B):=\operatorname P\left[X^{(s,\:x)}_t\in B\right]\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge s\ge0\text{ and }(x,B)\in\mathbb R\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R).$$

> How can we show that the transition semigroup $(\kappa_{s,\:t}:t\ge s\ge0)$ of $X$ is time-homogeneous, i.e. that $\kappa_{s,\:t}$ only depends on $t-s$ for all $t\ge s\ge0$?

Clearly, we may observe that $$X^{(0,\:x)}_h=x+\int_0^hb\left(X^{(0,\:x)}_r\right)\:{\rm d}r+\int_0^h\sigma\left(X^{(0,\:x)}_r\right)\:{\rm d}W_r\tag5$$ for all $h\ge0$ almost surely for all $x\in\mathbb R$, while $$X^{(s,\:x)}_{s+h}=x+\int_0^hb\left(X^{(s,\:x)}_{s+r}\right)\:{\rm d}r+\int_0^h\sigma\left(X^{(s,\:x)}_{s+r}\right)\:{\rm d}W_r^{(s)}\tag6$$ for all $h\ge0$ almost surely for all $s\ge0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$.

> My guess is that $(5)$ and $(6)$ imply that $\left(X^{(0,\:x)}_h\right)_{h\ge0}$ and $\left(X^{(s,\:x)}_{s+h}\right)_{h\ge0}$ have the same distribution (since $W$ and $W^{(s)}$ have the same distribution) for all $s\ge0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$. How can we show that rigorously and how can we conclude from that?

Comment: you seem very active around here, so why didn't you take some time look at my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978938/which-inequality-for-the-fourth-central-moment-do-we-need-to-apply-here/3038500#3038500)? I took me some time to think about my answer and write it down, so it would have been nice to get some feedback (or the bounty you had placed on the question).

Comment: @RobertoRastapopoulos Give me some time to get back to the problem. I'll take a look at your answer soon.