# Why isn't it trivial that pathwise uniqueness implies uniqueness in law?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider an SDE $${\rm d}X_t=b(t,X_t){\rm d}t+\sigma(t,X_t){\rm d}W_t\tag1$$ with Lipschitz continous $b,\sigma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and a Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t\ge0}$. We know that, given a filtered probability space and a Brownian motion on this space beforehand, there is a pathwise unique strong solution of $(1)$.

> How can we conclude that this solution is unique in law?

There is a well-known result by Yamada and Watanabe claiming that if weak solutions of $(1)$ are pathwise unique, then they are also unique in law. However, the proof is rather "complicated", while (at least in the setting described above) it seems to be trivial that $\operatorname P\left[X_t=\tilde X_t\text{ for all }t\ge0\right]$ implies that the finite-dimensional distributions of $X$ and $\tilde X$ coincide. What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "this solution" is unique in law? If you have two **strong** solutions to (1), then they are pathwise unique and hence unique in law... not too difficult to show this. It is, however, less immediate that any two **weak** solutions to (1) are unique in law. The trouble already starts with the fact that the weak solutions might be defined on different probability space (in particular we can't argue directly via pathwise uniqueness or things like that).

Comment: @saz That's what I mean. Why is, for example, [the Argumentation in Oksendal, Lemma 5.3.1](https://books.google.de/books?id=gizqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=%22Lemma+5.3.1.%22+oksendal%22+%22Then+the+same+uniqueness+argument%22&source=bl&ots=3kx77KJYDP&sig=ACfU3U2QRLFnozoR3k0qzM0BXJ65WAl_Ow&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8mZ-8zsjgAhUM3xoKHU0uAk8Q6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Lemma%205.3.1.%22%20oksendal%22%20%22Then%20the%20same%20uniqueness%20argument%22&f=false) rather complicated? (Note that he's consider strong solutions $X,Y$ inside the proof.)

Comment: I have a particular dislike for this book, sorry, don't expect me to explain what he's doing. As far as I remember, the idea of the proof is to construct a new probability space where both (weak) solutions live (kind of "embedding") and then to argue via pathwise uniqueness of the SDE.

Comment: It was just the best match for my question. I never worked with this book. The important conclusion is: I'm not missing anything, right? If there is a pathwise unique strong solution, this solution is trivially unique in law. I want to use this in order to conclude time-homogeneity of the strong solution of an autonomous SDE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004304/show-that-the-solution-of-an-autonomous-sde-is-a-time-homogeneous-markov-process

Comment: Yeah, you are not missing anything.