# Bound central moments of even order with raw moments of same order

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ be a probability space and consider a real-valued random variable $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. It holds
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 \leq \mathbb{E}[X^2].
$$
Is this true for higher moments of even order? Precisely, does it hold for $p = 1, 2, \ldots$
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^{2p}] \leq C(p)\mathbb{E}[X^{2p}],
$$
for some positive constant $C(p)$ depending only on $p$ and such that $C(1) = 1$?

**Edit:**

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591161/is-the-kth-central-moment-less-than-the-kth-raw-moment-for-even-k?rq=1) it is proved that the inequality above does not hold for $C(p) = 1$ for all $p = 1,2,\ldots$ Still, could it hold with a $p$-dependent proportionality constant?

**Edit 2:**

It is possible to prove that the inequality holds with $C(p) = 2^{2p}$ using Hölder's and Jensen's inequality. In particular, Hölder's inequality yields for any real numbers $a$ and $b$
$$
(a-b)^{2p} \leq 2^{2p-1}(a^{2p}+b^{2p}),
$$
so that by linearity of $\mathbb{E}$
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^{2p}] \leq 2^{2p-1}\left(\mathbb{E}[X^{2p}]+\mathbb{E}[X]^{2p}\right).
$$
Noew Jensen's inequality yields $\mathbb{E}[X]^{2p} \leq \mathbb{E}[X^{2p}]$ and we can conclude that
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^{2p}] \leq 2^{2p-1} \cdot 2 \mathbb{E}[X^{2p}]  =2^{2p}\mathbb{E}[X^{2p}].
$$
Is there any sharper bound? In this way, for $p = 1$ we obtain $C(1) = 4$ instead of $C(1) = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$C(p)=2^{2p-1}$ (gaining a factor 2) is possible. This answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3040487/484640 shows that inequality $E[(Y-E[Y])^{m}]\le E[Y^m]$ for nonnegative $Y$.
Admitting this result, write $X=X_+-X_-$ for the positive and negative parts.
By Jensen's inequality
$$
\frac{1}{2^m}E[(X-E[X])^m]
\le
\frac{E[(X_+-E[X_+])^m]
+
E[(X_--E[X_-])^m]}{2} 
\le
\frac{E[X_+^m]+
E[X_-^m]}{2}
= \frac{E[|X|^m]}{2}.
$$
With $m=2p$, $C(p)=2^{2p-1}$ holds. It is the same as taking $a=X_+-E[X_+]$ and $b=X_- - E[X_-]$ and taking expectation in the inequality $(a-b)^{2p}\le 2^{2p-1}(a^{2p}+b^{2p})$ given in the question.

Comment: @G.Gare Yes, since $|X|=X_+-X_-$ and $X_+X_-=0$.

Comment: Very nice. The fact that for $p=1$ we have $C(1) = 1$ is still not reached, though, as in your calculation we have $C(1) = 2$. How do you think this could be explained?

Comment: For example, it would be very good to obtain $2^{p-1}$.